# Check if Windows machine can act as a host in RDP connection

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, remote-desktop, rdp

I'm writing a program and I want to be sure that it will run only on Windows machines that can act as a host in RDP connection. For example, some Windows versions can't do such a thing – e.g. win7 basic, win7 home, win8.
I can check Windows version and compare it with list of RDP-host-compatible versions, but I wonder if there is а more common way to check this ability. Maybe some WinAPI method or a special registry key.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to know whether the Windows edition supports this, or whether or not the RDP service is listening for connections?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the first one.

Comment: I think your best bet is to hard code an edition check

Comment: @DavidHeffernan well, I suppose, it is the easiest solution. Thanks. Unfortunately, I can't mark it as an answer or can I?

Comment: I don't think you need to hurry to accept an answer. Give the question a little time.

Comment: [`OSVERSIONINFOEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724833): `VER_SUITE_TERMINAL` 
- Terminal Services is installed. This value is always set.
If `VER_SUITE_TERMINAL` is set but `VER_SUITE_SINGLEUSERTS` is not set, the system is running in application server mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like David Heffernan suggested edition check was hardcoded.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand [MSDN Remote Desktop Services Administration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383454%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the function [NetServerGetInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should give you the information you want.

```
LPSERVER_INFO_101 pSI = NULL;
if(NetServerGetInfo(NULL, 101, (LPBYTE*)&pSI) == NErr_Success) {
    const bool bIsTerminalServer = pSI->sv101_type & SV_TYPE_TERMINALSERVER;
    NetApiBufferFree(pSI);
}
```

Other newsgroup posts suggest to check if the service `TermService` is running (you can use `QueryServiceStatusEx` for that).

Comment: Nice, but it seems like this method is working only for the special configured servers, no? I can connect to my working computer with Win8.1 Pro by RDP, but bIsTerminalServer == false.

Comment: @nnatarr I updated my answer. On my Windows 7 the service was not running (Remote Desktop was disabled), when I enabled Remote Desktop the service was started. But when I disabled Remote Desktop again the service kept running. Maybe it still helps.

Comment: I need to know if the Windows edition supports acting like an RDP host. So, I think, I'll follow the advice of David Heffernan. Thanks for your help!